# paquete “fifer” in R 4.0.1

Tags: r, estructuras-de-datos, rstudio, librería, instalacion

Necesito una alternativa para poder hacer esto:

```
data_train<-fifer::stratified(data, c("spi"), 0.7)
```

Estoy intentando instalar `fifer` porque es el paquete con el que trabaje originalmente.

Al tratar de instalar fifer usando:

```
Install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("dustinfife/fifer")
library(fifer)
```

Me da este error:

> lazy loading failed for package ‘fifer’
> removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/fifer’ installation of package ‘/var/folders/xm/9dcx327x1bxg292grp2nvc_h0000gq/T//Rtmpk57rTj/filef8f4d6a7b9/fifer_1.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Bienvenida Sol Contreras a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido instalar `fifer` finalmente siguiendo con esta secuencia:

```
install.packages("mice")
install.packages("plotrix")
remotes::install_github("dustinfife/flexplot")
remotes::install_github("dustinfife/fifer")
```

Tanto los paquetes `mice` como `plotrix` fueron paquetes que no pudieron instalarse automáticamente, en cada intento se mencionaba la falta de estos.

Comment: Gracias!.. lo logre <3